# DataGrip: How to chop long 'returning' part?

Tags: postgresql, intellij-idea, formatting, jetbrains-ide, datagrip

I have the following problem with formatting a PostgreSQL query in Datagrip (and also in all other JetBrains products regarding PG queries):

```sql
update some_table
set some_column = 42
where id = 42
returning val_a as "valA",
          val_b as "valB",
          val_c as "valC",
          val_d as "valD",
          val_e as "valE",
          val_f as "valF",
          val_g as "valG";
```

When I now use the built-in SQL formatter, DataGrip produces this:

```sql
update some_table
set some_column = 42
where id = 42
returning val_a as "valA", val_b as "valB", val_c as "valC", val_d as "valD", val_e as "valE", val_f as "valF", val_g as "valG";
```

You see what the issue is: All returned values are in one line (it even ignores my max-line-length setting). I tried different settings in my IDE but to no avail. Note that for now, I don't care if the returned `val`s are indented or aligned or whatever, I just want the query to be "readable".

Looking forward to a solution and thanks in advance!

Comment: Feel free to follow: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-16107

Answer (score -1):

There is no option for that :( Please, file a request
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=DBE

Comment: Done! https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-16107